# How do you write a custom object containing an array of custom objects of another type to firestore in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a class Poll and a class Question. Each object of Poll has an array of objects of Question type. I have to write the objects of Poll class to firestore. I created a converter for Poll but I have received an error-
`` Uncaught FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data (via `toFirestore()`). Unsupported field value: a custom object (found in document Polls/Redundant/topic/PollContent) ``
Here is my code-

```
class Poll{
    constructor(topic, meantFor, type, isAnonymous, questions){
        this.topic = topic;
        this.meantFor = meantFor;
        this.type = type;
        this.isAnonymous = isAnonymous;
        this.questions = questions;
    }
}

pollConverter = {
    toFirestore: function(poll) {
        return {
            topic: poll.topic,
            meantFor: poll.meantFor,
            type: poll.type,
            isAnonymous: poll.isAnonymous,
            questions: poll.questions
        }
    },
    fromFirestore: function(snapshot, options){
        const data = snapshot.data(options);
        return new Poll(data.topic, data.meantFor, data.type, data.isAnonymous, data.questions)
    }
}

class Question{
    constructor(questionStr, type, options){
        this.questionStr = questionStr;
        this.type = type;
        this.options = options;
    }
}

questionConverter = {
    toFirestore: function(question) {
        return {
            questionStr: question.questionStr,
            type: question.type,
            options: question.options
        }
    },
    fromFirestore: function(snapshot, options){
        const data = snapshot.data(options);
        return new Question(data.questionStr, data.type, data.options)
    }
}
```

I used the following to write the object-

```
Q1= new Question("abc",0,null);
Q2= new Question("xyz",0,null);
P1= new Poll("topic","meant","tp","anon",[Q1,Q2]);
db=firebase.firestore()
db.collection("Polls").doc("Redundant").collection("topic").doc("PollContent").withConverter(pollConverter).set(P1)
```

I don't understand how I should specify that the code should use the questionConverter for the questions in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is only one converter used and the `questionCoverter` is not doing it's job. I suppose that you want to use it separately, but it's also possible to call it inside `pullConverter`. I have used the code on my side and it worked after following change (just one line in `question` field):

```
pollConverter = {
    toFirestore: function(poll) {
        return {
            topic: poll.topic,
            meantFor: poll.meantFor,
            type: poll.type,
            isAnonymous: poll.isAnonymous,
            questions: poll.questions.map(q => questionConverter.toFirestore(q))
        }
    },
...
```

I hope it will help!